# Passing text to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm just starting in on javascript and working on a problem that our instructor gave us. We have an html site with four buttons, each of the buttons has a color, and when you hit the button it changes the background/text color. Sample HTML and javascript below.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <ul id="switcher">
    <li id="grayButton"></li>
    <li id="whiteButton"></li>
    <li id="blueButton"></li>
    <li id="yellowButton"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
document.getElementById("yellowButton").onclick = turnYellow;

function turnYellow (){
   document.getElementById("wrapper").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
   document.getElementById("wrapper").style.color = "orange";
    }
```

I got that to work fine, but I was trying to refactor so that my function was more generic:

```
document.getElementById("grayButton").onclick = changeColor("gray", "white");

function changeColor(backColor, frontColor) {
   document.getElementById("wrapper").style.backgroundColor = backColor;
   document.getElementById("wrapper").style.color = frontColor;  
}
```

and I can't figure out why that doesn't work. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call your function in an anonymous function, adding the parameters `()` caused the function to be invoked immediately:

```
document.getElementById("grayButton").onclick = function() {
    changeColor("gray", "white");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"element.onlick" event requires a function object (callable/callback) not a return value. Thus it should be:

```
document.getElementById("grayButton").onclick = function(){
    changeColor("gray", "white");
}
```

Also, HTML5 [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) seems like a great idea:

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id="wrapper"> 
  <ul id="switcher"> 
    <li data-bg-color="red"  data-color="white" onclick="changeColor(this)">
       red/white
    </li> 
    <li data-bg-color="gray" data-color="black" onclick="changeColor(this)">
       gray/black
    </li>
  </ul> 
</div>

<script>   
  function changeColor(el) {   
      var wrapper =  document.getElementById("wrapper");  
      wrapper.style.color = el.getAttribute('data-color'); 
      wrapper.style.backgroundColor = el.getAttribute('data-bg-color'); 
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

- [HTML5 Data Attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution [My example](http://plnkr.co/edit/WSWRd8Izp1JojqafpB3T?p=preview)

HTML

```
 <body onload="start()">
    <div id="wrapper">
      <ul>
        <li data-params="yellow,orange">Hit me</li>
        <li data-params="green,darkgreen">Hit me</li>
        <li data-params="aqua,blue">Hit me</li>
        <li data-params="chocolate,brow">Hit me</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
```

JavaScript

```
function start(){
  //Get necesary elements
  var list = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
  //Adding event
  for(var i in list){
    list[i].addEventListener("click", changeStyle);
  }
}

function changeStyle(){
  var params  = this.dataset.params.split(","),
      wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");

  wrapper.style.backgroundColor = params[0];
  wrapper.style.color =  params[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply called the function `changeColor` and assigned its return value which is `undefined` to the event handler.

I am pretty sure it even worked and changed the text color and background color for that element but not like what you expected i.e. synchronously vs asynchronously.

You just need to leave a reference to the event handler like this `changeColor` without the parentheses like what you did in the first example and the event handler would take care of everything for you when the event occurs/fires and it detects it.